# How could I know how many chars to allocate before calling std::to_chars?

Tags: c++, c++17

There is few examples about `std::to_chars` and I only found an example from cppreference:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<char, 10> str;

    if(auto [p, ec] = std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), 42);
       ec == std::errc())
        std::cout << std::string_view(str.data(), p - str.data());
}
```

It hardcodes a 10-sized array which I think is not good ... How could I know exactly how many chars to allocate before calling `std::to_chars`?

```
float f = ...;
std::string str;
// HERE
str.resize(????);
std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), f);
```

Comment: Use `stringstream` and have the storage resize itself.

Comment: For printing numbers as base N, you can take the Nth log of the input and add 1 to know how many digits you need. E.g. log10(1000)=3. Not sure if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @wobr I want to convert `float`s. I added some info to the question.

Comment: As per @Ayxan answer, use to_string

Comment: Right. Anything is better than a preallocated buffer of fixed size. That fixed size is just a bug waiting to happen. Exceptions to this rule are few and far between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function has been designed for some high speed conversions without too much overhead. It will check an overflow and return an error code. However, if you want to know in advance, how many digits the conversion will result in, you can use

```
std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10
```

Please note: As its name and the documentation says, `max_digits10` is talking about the maximum number of *digits* needed. It does not take into account all signs and a potential "e". So you would need additional space for those none digit characters, worst case 7. So, to be on the safe side, you could always add 7 to the size of the array.

Your code could look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <charconv>

int main()
{
    std::array<char, std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10> str;

    float v = 1000000.0 + 1.0 / 3.0;

    if (auto [p, ec] = std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), v);ec == std::errc())
        std::cout << std::string_view(str.data(), p - str.data());
}
```

You will find more information [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Please note: If you want to use a `std::string` and its underlying buffer, then you must add 1 to `std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10` in the `std::string`'s `resize` function.

Again, to be on the absolute safe side here, add 8 to the size to include potential special characters.

Comment: "*However, I would not recommend to use the underlying buffer of the std::string directly.*" Why not? That's what `data` was added for. It's a contiguous array of characters, so using it is perfectly legitimate code.

Comment: @NicolBolas is it really an array? I don't think it's an array type. More like a contiguous block of memory.

Comment: @Ayxan: "*is it really an array?*" Yes. The standard requires that `basic_string` store an array. The standard requires that any pointer to a character in the string to work exactly like a pointer to a character in an array of that size. "*I don't think it's an array type.*" It doesn't have to be. The standard requires that pointers to characters in the string work correctly.

Comment: @NicolBolas so it's an array but it's not an array type

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is misleading.
If we try to print e.g. minimum possible float, it wouldn't work unless we add at least 5 to `max_digits10` . See here:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fjqY67dz1
This happens because `max_digits10` is only about digits in the number but does not include: possible `-` for number, `+/-` for exponent, number of digits in exponent (max 2 for float), digit separator, exponent symbol. So we need `+6` for float and `+7` for double to cover all cases. It would be much easier if such constant was provided by the standard of course.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use `std::string` if you don't know the size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  int const i = 42;
  auto const str = std::to_string(i);
  std::cout << str;
}
```